# Do particles, quarks, atoms really move in space, or is it field disturbance-wave that moves in S-T with speed $c$? How particles move in S-T in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, spacetime, wave-particle-duality, matter

As I understand particles are localized fields (16fields+g). Can you explain on hydrogen atom example that moves in space vacuum. Does it really moving, or it is continious field disturbance interaction that travels in space time since BB inflation. As analogy with 2D water wave. Does matter fundamentally travels or it is all "mathematical" fields disturbance that moves. If so, how it is working on macro scale, and on human eye world.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is elementary particles that are directly modeled mathematically with fields in quantum field theory. atoms and molecules are more complicated representations, as they are bound states  of protons and neutrons and electrons,  and protons and neutrons are bound states of quarks  which are elementary particles and can be modeled with QFT,  though quantum field theory models can be used to model (i.e. describe and predict) a number of physical phenomena  , like superconductivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantum fields of the Standard Model are Lorentz invariant, so moving is in the eye of the beholder. Any particle with mass has a rest-frame, and the minimum energy of 1 quanta is $E_0=mc^2$. Most relativistic QFT treatments are in the momentum domain, but if we consider a quanta of say, an electron, in its rest frame, so $E_0 = m_ec^2$, its propagation in time is an unobservable rotating phase:

$$ e^{im_ec^2/\hbar} $$

Ofc, that's really a quantum mechanics view.

The fields are not like water waves, or anything in a medium. There is no medium. I would first master classical EM waves in SR, and then move up. For instance, if I have a plane wave from a helium neon laser with 633 nm wavelength (internally) and shoot it into space. A few light years later: is the wavelength still 633 nm? (no expanding universe..strictly flat space time)...

When you're answer is "No, that really doesn't mean anything", then consider rQFTs.